# iphone: Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, app-store

We have a company account and I have admin rights on it and I am trying to Login into to

https://itunesconnect.apple.com

but its giving error.

**Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect.**

I can log on to Apple site and have admin rights on our companies account but could not post Application to App Store because I do not have Team Agents rights and there it gives error

"Only Team Agents are authorized to prepare and submit applications for distribution."

Now I want to post application to App store so that it could be ready for testing for multiple people.

Comment: Are you also the team leader of the developer account? (ie, user #1 who launched said developer account) By default, I believe this user is granted access to ITC and then can add additional users to the ITC interface from there too.

Comment: ya... I have admin rights and can make account for other user too, make provision profiles and can deploy application to device. but I do not have Team Agent rights

Comment: @Azhar Yes i am also facing problem.Can u fix this issue.If yes please provide guidelines to me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I send an Email to IOS ([eurodev@apple.com](http://eurodev@apple.com)) and they send me this response which clears the conflict.

> Please be advised that you currently have an Enterprise Developer
>   Account. As an Enterprise Developer you do not have access to iTunes
>   Connect, because the Enterprise Program is for internal app
>   distribution. Therefore you cannot submit apps to the App Store, so
>   there is no access to iTunes Connect as a Enterprise Developer.
>
> If you wish to submit apps to the App Store we ask that you enroll
>   into the iOS Company Developer Program.
>
> Please note, if you would like to join the iOS Company Developer you
>   may visit the following link:
>
> http://developer.apple.com/programs/
>
> Additionally, your iOS Company Enrollment and Program will need to be
>   managed separate from your Enterprise Program this means you need to
>   create a new Apple ID and also pay the enrollment cost as well.

Answer (score 18):

Ask your team admin to log into iTunes Connect, in the home page click on the item "Manage Users". Here you'll find a list of Members approved to access iTunes Connect. Add a new user and select user type as iTunes connect user. Fill in the other details, the new user will get a confirmation email from Apple, once you click on the confirmation, you'll be able to access iTunes connect using your Apple ID.

[image]

[image: Select User type]

[image: Add new user]

Comment: What happens if the new user already has an AppleID?  Any idea how to get around the "The email address you entered already belongs to an iTunes Connect account. To continue, enter a different email address." error?

Comment: @Nelga What's happening here is that the user you're trying to add is already associated with a different iTunes Connect account and each Apple ID can only be associated with one iTunes Connect account. The other person you're trying to add will have to create a new Apple ID.

Answer (score 4):

The Provisioning Portal and iTunes Connect are two different things with different permissions and accounts. Just because you have access to the Provisioning Portal and can create profiles etc does not mean that you automatically have access to ITC.

The person who first set up your iPhone Developer account is the 'team agent'. They will automatically have access to ITC with 'admin' privs. You need to get them to add you as a user with 'admin' or 'technical' privs. You can then access ITC and manage application submissions on their behalf.

Comment: This doesn't work for a brand new account of mine (using 'team agent'). iOS Dev Center and all works, but iTunes Connect does not. This is a normal company profile. I assume that it takes awhile for all systems to update.

Comment: @Jonny I have the same exact problem. I am the team agent and I can access iOS Dev Center fine but I can't access iTunes Connect because of "Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect". Any idea how long this took for you? For us it has been around 2 days.

Comment: I think it took a few hours... but I forgot. But not like 2 days.

Comment: hi all, i also got in same problem, i have main admin account but still not access iTunes Connect... :(
please help...