# itunesconnect login - Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

I am a beginner iPhone developer. I have an apple ID and password. This apple ID and password work on https://developer.apple.com but not on https://itunesconnect.apple.com. It's not working on itunes connect. I get the error: `Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect`. please give any solution and suggestion for this.

Comment: Do you have a paid account?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697327/iphone-apple-id-does-not-have-permission-to-access-itunes-connect

Comment: @DaleeDavis Yes i am getting the same error while login to https://itunesconnect.apple.com and i paid amount also

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me on my second iTunes account after I had just signed up as a corporate account... I just had to wait for them to verify my DUNS number. If this isn't the case I'm sure they are still verifying other things... it took me 14 days until I could access iTunes connect... on my first iTunes account (4-5 years ago) it took 30 days before I could upload apps after accessing iTunesConnect (bank verification) ... (Now a-days this takes less than 1 day)